# Change gender in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook account and during registration I must have checked the gender as "male". I realized this, when people told me they see messages like "Suggest friends to *him*".

Is it possible to change this gender setting? Or will I have to remove my account and create a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Login to Facebook
2. Click on your name in the upper-left corner
3. Click on **Update Info**
   [image]
4. On **Basic Info** click **Edit**
   [image]
5. On the drop-down menu, change your sex
   [image]
6. On the same drop-down, click **Save**